# What is the performance improvement of using azure caching?

Tags: azure-caching

Here is a candid question. Azure caching (any of its flavors) is marketed as a way to improve performance.

I can understand how it can help scaling, by not hitting a SQL database on every request and therefore helping not to make the database a bottleneck.

However my understanding of performance is that a network call is extremely expensive compared to a local disk access or any reasonable local computation. So I would expect that most of the cost of going to an azure database would be related to the network access (particularly if the SQL database keeps hot data in RAM). In this case how does going to a network cache help to improve performance vs going to the database directly?

Comment: I don;t know much about Azure.. but from a technical point of view, disk access may be, and most often is, much more expensive than network... On the other side of the network call, there's probably a service running with Data in RAM... on a disk.. well, its a disk, its slow!